# Call the method from C# to C++CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, wrapper

I have to call C# managed class library in C++CLI which has the files with Wrapper.cpp and Wrapper.h.

My managed class library includes the code like:

```
namespace MyClassLbrary
{
  public class MyImage
  {
     public void TestImage(DrawImage drawImage)
     { 
     }
}
 public class DrawImage
 {

  }
}
```

Next Step should be

I have to call this  TestImage(DrawImage darwImage) method from C++CLI i.e.in Wrapper.cpp.
   I have to write all the unmanaged code in my Wrapper.h file. related to this. but the problem is I have to declare this TestImage(DrawImage drawImage) in my Wrapper.h file which contains the object of my c# managed class .**I am importing that C# class library in my C++CLI.** Then how to call that method in my Wrapper.h file which contains only the things related to unmanaged code. Please let me know if you have  any kind of generalized solution so that I can call my Methods like TestImage.

Comment: This is *very* easy to do, you click the Add New Reference button and select the C# assembly.  And instantly, any public classes in the C# assembly become available in your C++/CLI code.  You do **not** want to declare them in your C++/CLI code, that doesn't work.  The corollary then is to be sure to avoid circular dependencies, the likelier reason you ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate header files, and put your actual unmanaged code in .cpp files.